# How to get percentage for a field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I would like to get percentage for a given field value. I am achieving this in excel by using formula. Is there a way to write down formula in SSRS?

I attached images here.

I need this

[image: I need this]

In excel i achieved by using formula, how to get this one in SSRS?
[image: I achieved in excel by this, How to get this one in SSRS]

Comment: I got the partial answer here. How to get the sum of percentage? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible.

Use below expression

```
=Round(100 * (ReportItems!Number.Value / ReportItems!Number1.Value),2)
```

Here, **ReportItems!Number.Value** is the textbox name of **Name Texbox** and **ReportItems!Number1.Value** is the textbox name of **Total Textbox**.

See the below Image, It's working fine.

[image]

To Get **Sum of percentage**.

I would suggest to follow below things,

Go to Report properties, then Go To Code and then create the following function.

```
Public Sum_Perc As Integer = 0 
Public Function PercentageSum(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
    Sum_Perc = Sum_Perc + value    
 Return Sum_Perc
End Function
```

Now, beside **Name** - Create Placeholder and set font to white as we don't required to show calculation on this cell. Do like below image[image].

Now, Set Expression like below image and text like this,

```
=Code.Sum_Perc
```

[image]

*Hope, It will be helpful to you. Thanks*

Comment: Thanks for your help. I never used Report items. Please could you suggest me some websites to learn more about report items. It worked perfectly. How can i get Sum of percentage?

Comment: I got the partial answer here. How to get the sum of percentage? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: of course to get sum - you must have to use your own logic. This can be achieved thru custom code. I've read answer and I hope it will be working fine! Seems there may be chances of issue - while using lookup_Sum. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: My sum is working on one report it's not working on another one. I am trying your way. Did you renamed your placeholder to sum_perc? why do we have to create placeholder, can't we achieve this one in the same cell? It's not working for me. please help me.

Comment: You have to follow what I already mentioned above. Need to use place holder. as on details row we are getting first sum value,  so from all those 3 rows we need to calculate total sum in percentage. Please understand the whole scenario why we are doing like this. Hope you will understand why I have used place holder.

Comment: @hari - can you please update me, this solution is working or not?

Comment: Hey @Pedram, It's not working. I fixed the issue by using SQL. I am appreciating your help. Thanks

Comment: Don't know why it's not working there. It should definitely work. I have checked completely and it's working properly.

Comment: i got 98% on one report (in excel i got 100%). On another report sum is starting from zero for every page. i.e., if one page total is 42%, on the next page it will start from 0 not from 42%. BTW I am using 2008 R2, if does it matter.

Answer (score 0):

I used this custom code to get the percentage sum

```
Public Total_lookup_Sum As Integer = 0 
Public Function Lookup_Sum(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer
    Total_lookup_Sum = Total_lookup_Sum + value    
 Return Total_lookup_Sum 
End Function
```

and i used this expression in tablix

```
=round(100*code.lookup_Sum(Reportitems!Textbox34.value),2)
```

source [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/002c459a-2260-437a-a53c-a380bc2299d0/sum-column-gives-error-aggregate-functions-can-be-used-only-on-report-items-contained-in-page?forum=sqlreportingservices)